# Modal dialog that is opened using JavaScript is not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, modal-dialog

Good day everyone.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and datatable as my main source of table design.
I am able to create DataTable buttons that displays a modal when it is clicked but the problem is that the modal have height that is bigger than the page. supposedly when i scroll down the lower part of the modal should appear but it is the main page that is scrolling down and the lower part of the modal is not showing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code for my DataTable

```
<table id="exampledatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Code</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Type</th>
        <th>Industry Type</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Off Day 1</th>
        <th>Off Day 2</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my script for the DataTable button that calls a html Modal

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#exampledatatable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        text: '',
                        titleAttr: 'Create New Record',
                        action: function (e, dt, node, config)
                                {
                                    $('#generalCusModal12').show();
                                }
                    }]
                    });
                 });
```

And here is my code for html Modal

```
<div id="generalCusModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-employee">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"><img class="crud" src="~/Images/profile.png" />Customer Records Management</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="lbl_custinfo">General</h4>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Code</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<Auto>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Company Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" disabled>
                            <option value="">CUSTOMER</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected></option>
                            <option>WALK-IN</option>
                            <option>RESIDENTIAL</option>
                            <option>COMPANY</option>
                            <option>SCHOOL</option>
                            <option>BANK</option>
                            <option>CLINIC</option>
                            <option>RESTAURANT</option>
                            <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                            <option>HOTEL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Industry Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>ADVERTISING AGENCIES</option>
                            <option>BUSINESS PROCESS OUTSOURCING</option>
                            <option>ENTERTAINMENT COMPANY</option>
                            <option>FOOD COMPANY</option>
                            <option>TECHNOLOGY</option>
                            <option>TELECOMMUNICATION</option>
                            <option>PHARMACEUTICAL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 1</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>MONDAY</option>
                            <option>TUESDAY</option>
                            <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                            <option>THURSDAY</option>
                            <option>FRIDAY</option>
                            <option>SATURDAY</option>
                            <option>SUNDAY</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 2</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>MONDAY</option>
                            <option>TUESDAY</option>
                            <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                            <option>THURSDAY</option>
                            <option>FRIDAY</option>
                            <option>SATURDAY</option>
                            <option>SUNDAY</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Website</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--MODAL BODY-->

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#custLocationModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tied adding some CSS styling to your modal.Like "overflow-y: scroll;"

Comment: Yes I already tried it. but didn't work for me. I also observed that there is no blurred background outside the modal and the 'x' on the upper right side which is supposedly for closing the modal is not working.

Comment: You need to add a reference to jQuery then bootstrap css and bootstrap.js

Comment: but i already added reference for those.